How to enable interactivity for pages/components within a Razor Class Library for a Blazor App with .NET 8?
I am currently working on developing an application in Blazor with .NET 8, and I am designing it to be modular. The main app is a Blazor project with server-side rendering, and I have structured it so that there is a folder for modules. Inside this folder, I have subfolders, each containing additional projects.
In my current setup, I have a Blazor project within my solution as the main app. This allows me to divide the application into several modules, each consisting of three essential projects. For example:
Module "Configurations":

Class Library – Configurations.BLL: Business logic for the module.
Class Library – Configurations.Domain: Models, validations, etc., for the module.
Razor Class Library – Configurations.UI: Pages/components to be rendered for the module.

I have managed to make my main app recognize the routes of the pages inside the Razor Class Library. However, I am struggling with interactivity. For instance, I cannot add functionality to a button because the attribute @renderMode interactiveServer doesn't seem to be recognized or compatible with this type of project. As a result, I can render the component, but I cannot make it interactive.
What I tried was changing some project settings to enable the use of RazorComponents:
<EnableRazorComponents>true</EnableRazorComponents>
I expected this to make the pages work as Blazor understands and handles these components, but It didn't work.
At this point, I am questioning whether this is the right approach or if there is a better alternative for building this type of modular app.

If you want to set interactivity on a per page/component basis, I think your route components need to be in the deployment project.  They can be simple wrappers around a component in a library that implements the primary functionality.

Do you have any example about it? I tried by removing the @page from my component in my RCL, then, in my main app, I created a file named "ConfigWrapper" and added the @page on this one, Then inside of it I called my "Configuration" component from RCL, but It still not working as expected, It renders, but still with no interactivity.

Alright, it seems like I've found the solution, or at least one of them, by following Shaun Curtis's recommendations. The thing is, even though I needed the Wrapper, I was also missing some directives in my RCL project. So, I created a file in the root of my RCL project called _Imports.razor and added the following:
Configuracion -> _Imports
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization

This way, my buttons went from looking like this:

Before photo

To looking like this:

after photo

Which achieves what I was aiming for—a way for events to be recognized. After this, I simply used a Wrapper in my Blazor project that contains the route where I want to render this component and, lastly, the component with the rendering mode I want to use:
Wrapper looks like this
@page "/configuration/ui/general/general-configuration"

<ConfigurationComponent @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

And with that, it allowed proper interaction:
Demo gif

I was just about to pen an answer, but I see you've got there by yourself.   You need to imports to provide the necessary library references.
